# Is the Boeing 777 low speed warning same as the master caution warning?

Tags: boeing-777

Is the Boeing 777 low speed warning the same as the master caution warning?

If the answer is no, I would appreciate an answer with a link to a recording of the low speed warning so I can tell the difference.

Answer (score 4):

The caution message AIRSPEED LOW comes with the *normal master caution beeper*:

> **Airspeed Low**
>
> The EICAS caution message AIRSPEED LOW is displayed and the box around
> the current airspeed indication on the PFD is highlighted amber if airspeed is
> below minimum maneuvering speed. [...]
>
> | Message | Level | Aural | Message Logic |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | AIRSPEED LOW | Caution | Beeper | Airspeed is below minimum maneuvering speed. |

<sup>(Boeing 777 FCOMv2 15.20.9 - Warning Systems - System Description)</sup>

This has been criticized because the beeper might not be enough to draw the flight crew's attention to the low speed in an emergency situation:

> Boeing also has a "caution tone" for low airspeed on the 777, along with versions of the 747, according to an FAA panel studying the issue. But other planes have a verbal warning such as "airspeed low." Clifford said the 777 tone "has proven to not capture the pilot's attention in these low airspeed circumstances." [...]
>
> Airbus has a warning that says "speed speed speed" every five seconds between 2,000 and 100 feet when an aircraft goes too slow.

<sup>([USA TODAY](https://eu.usatoday.com/story/news/nation/2013/07/11/aircraft-speed-warning-asiana-flight-214/2508863/))</sup>